# How can I prevent exponents from appearing in an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I've found posts dealing with showing/hiding exponents for numbers, like in scientific notation. But what if I have a general expression? I have an expression like this,

```
p[{1,2}] p[{2,3}]^2 p[{4,5}]
```

and the exponent is screwing up a replacement rule I'd like to use. I'm sure I could find a workaround but if there's a way to make this appear as

```
p[{1,2}] p[{2,3}] p[{2,3}] p[{4,5}]
```

that would make my life much easier. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the replacement you want to do? Maybe you can work around the problem by modifying the replacing rule.

Comment: The replacement is essentially just combining components that have elements in common. So my example would get replaced by `p[{1,2,3}] p[{4,5}]`. I actually think I've found a way around it, although not in the most elegant way.

Comment: How about this?: `Times @@ p /@ 
  Union @@@ Gather[
    p[{1, 2}] p[{2, 3}]^2 p[{4, 5}] /. a_^b_ :> a /. 
     HoldPattern@Times[a__] :> Sequence @@@ {a}, Intersection[#, #2] != {} &]`

Comment: It is not clear why in your post you say you need the repeating `p[{2,3}]` while in your comment you show that at the end you don't take into account this repeated element ... ?

Comment: @SquareOne the idea is that the repeated element gets combined into a single element, because even though it's the same it has elements in common. Thanks for your post though.

Comment: @mathers101 In that case my answer would have been: `expr /. Power[x_, n_Integer] -> x //. Times[p[x_], p[y_]] /; IntersectingQ[x, y] :> p[Union[x, y]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was commented, you should probably tell us also about the problematic rule you cannot use but anyway you might be interested in the following approach:

As you (should) know, everything in Mathematica is an [*expression*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), in other words it can be expressed as `f[x,y,...]`

Your expression:

```
expr = p[{1, 2}] p[{2, 3}]^2 p[{4, 5}]
```

is actually interpreted as:

```
FullForm[expr]
```

> **`Times[p[List[1,2]],Power[p[List[2,3]],2],p[List[4,5]]]`**

If you are already familiar with replacement rules then you'll certainly understand the following replacement which will transform your expression in a form close to what you'd like:

Given this function:

```
myTimes[x_, n_Integer] := myTimes @@ ConstantArray[x, n]
```

see what happens here:

```
expr /. Power -> myTimes /. Times -> myTimes
```

> `myTimes[myTimes[p[{2,3}],p[{2,3}]],p[{1,2}],p[{4,5}]]`

Almost done. Let's add the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) property to function `myTimes`:

```
SetAttributes[myTimes, Flat]
```

and do again the same replacement than previously:

```
newexpr = expr /. Power -> myTimes /. Times -> myTimes
```

> **`myTimes[p[{2, 3}], p[{2, 3}], p[{1, 2}], p[{4, 5}]]`**

That's it. The idea is to work on this new and temporary expression with your set of replacement rules. Then, to go back in real world:

```
newexpr /. myTimes -> Times
```

> `p[{1,2}] p[{2,3}]^2 p[{4,5}]`